# How to store large values (10MB) using key-value store database?

Tags: key-value-store, leveldb, lmdb, rocksdb

Consider a system that requires the store of mostly small values (1-1000 bytes), but in some cases, it needs to store a large value (10MB). It contains a list of hashes (think a list of public keys for EDDSA signature)

In Ethereum, the storage is done via PATRICIA TIRE, but I dont think that is necessary. Does anyone know of a good way to handle such large values with a key/store database?

Comment: how about just use filesystem or product like s3

Comment: Can you use the filesystem or s3? Or is that a constraint

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to store large binary object (aka. blobs) with foundationdb:

```py
from uuid import uuid4
from uuid import UUID
from collections import namedtuple

from hashlib import blake2b as hasher
from more_itertools import sliced

import found


class BStoreException(found.BaseFoundException):
    pass


BSTORE_SUFFIX_HASH = [b'\x01']
BSTORE_SUFFIX_BLOB = [b'\x02']

BStore = namedtuple('BStore', ('name', 'prefix_hash', 'prefix_blob',))


def make(name, prefix):
    prefix = list(prefix)
    out = BStore(name, tuple(prefix + BSTORE_SUFFIX_HASH), tuple(prefix + BSTORE_SUFFIX_BLOB))
    return out


async def get_or_create(tx, bstore, blob):
    hash = hasher(blob).digest()
    key = found.pack((bstore.prefix_hash, hash))
    maybe_uid = await found.get(tx, key)
    if maybe_uid is not None:
        return UUID(bytes=maybe_uid)
    # Otherwise create the hash entry and store the blob with a new uid
    # TODO: Use a counter and implement a garbage collector, and implement
    # bstore.delete
    uid = uuid4()
    found.set(tx, key, uid.bytes)
    for index, slice in enumerate(sliced(blob, found.MAX_SIZE_VALUE)):
        found.set(tx, found.pack((bstore.prefix_blob, uid, index)), bytes(slice))
    return uid


async def get(tx, bstore, uid):
    key = found.pack((bstore.prefix_blob, uid))
    out = b''
    async for _, value in found.query(tx, key, found.next_prefix(key)):
        out += value
    if out == b'':
        raise BStoreException('BLOB should be in database: uid={}'.format(uid))
    return out
```

Taken from https://github.com/amirouche/asyncio-foundationdb/blob/main/found/bstore.py